# Batch insert into Elasticsearch is getting frozen after several thousands of inserts

Tags: java, spring, csv, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm trying to insert huge (~5GB, 600k records) csv file into ES. I'm doing it using spring-data and elasticsearchtemplate via batchInsert. After around every 100k inserts ES got frozen to undefined amount of time and wake up after around 5-10 minutes, it inserts next 100k records suspends again and so on. And every time waiting time became higher and higher and can reach hours.
I suspect that ES is reindexing just inserted records and I tried to disable auto-refresh but result is the same. I realize that reindexing is must but can I pause it and reindex after I insert all records?

```
version: '3.8'

services:          
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.4.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
```

The entity I'm trying to save:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Document(indexName = "index-name")
public class DataDocument {

    @Id
    @ToString.Include
    private Long uid;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, storeNullValue = true, index = true)
    private String indexField1;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, storeNullValue = true, index = true)
    private String indexField2;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, storeNullValue = true, index = true)
    private String indexField3;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, storeNullValue = true, index = true)
    private String indexField4;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, storeNullValue = true, index = true)
    private String indexField5;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, storeNullValue = true, index = false)
    private String notIndexField1;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, storeNullValue = true, index = false)
    private String notIndexField2
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, storeNullValue = true, index = false)
    private String notIndexField3;
//more 30 nonindexfields

}
```

And this is how I'm trying to save it:

```
//option 1: using respository public interface DataRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<DataDocument, Long>
        public long saveInBatch(Iterable<DataCsv> list) {
            long batchSize = Iterables.size(list);
            log.info("Received insert-batch of size={}", batchSize);
            final var documentList = mapper.mapAsIterable(list);
            repository.saveAll(documentList);
            return batchSize;
        }

//option 2: using ElasticsearchRestTemplate
        public long bulkSave(List<DataCsv> list) {
            log.info("Received bulk-insert of size={}", list.size());
            final var queryList = list.stream()
                    .map(mapper::map)
                    .map(e -> new IndexQueryBuilder().withObject(e).build())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //looks like withRefreshPolicy is not affecting anything
            final var result = elasticsearchRestTemplate
                    .bulkIndex(queryList, BulkOptions.builder().withRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.NONE).build(), IndexCoordinates.of("index-name"));
            return result.size();
        }
```

I tried different batch sizes: 100, 1000, 10000 - difference is neglectable

Here is example of log:

```
2022-08-02 03:41:17.744  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 03:41:20.313  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 03:41:22.887  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:23:47.785  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:23:56.669  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:23:59.304  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:24:01.913  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:24:04.360  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:24:07.109  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:24:09.619  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:24:12.023  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:24:14.528  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 04:24:17.118  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
2022-08-02 09:16:20.208  INFO 10840 --- [nio-5000-exec-1] c.o.h.p.service.DataService      : Received insert-batch of size=10000
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I make work RefreshPolicy?
2. How can I boost batch insert,maybe there are other options besides RefreshPolicy?
3. Is it ok to have such pauses during saving?

Comment: try to run your application with G1GC and see if it is still freezing.

Comment: @Pirate nope the same. 
CMD java  -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx2048m
I believe frozen not java app but response from ES

Comment: ES indexing is async (unless you refresh on every bulk, which makes it very slow). SO when you fire many bulk requests at once, they get into a queue, and when the queue fills up it doesn't accept any more indexing unless it's processed. It shouldn't take minutes and hours though. Try to run it on a larger machine with more RAM and larger heap?